# Why does "prepareCall" throw a NumberFormatException?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, dao

I'm writing a software in Java that needs to interact with a database (MySQL Workbench on localhost). In my DAO classes I retrieve a global database connection, which gets opened if it's not already. When my program calls "prepareCall" a NumberFormatException gets thrown. This happens only in some (most) queries but not in others, even though the code doesn't change.

I also wanted to point out that the query executes fine in workbench.

**DAO**

```
public static User selectPersonalInfo(Integer id) throws SQLException {
        CallableStatement stmt = null;
        ResultSet res = null;
        User user = null;

        try {
            Connection conn = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
            stmt = conn.prepareCall(RoutinesIdentifier.GET_USER);
            res = RoutinesManager.bindParametersAndExec(stmt, id);
            
            if (res.first()){               
                user = new User(res.getString("email"), res.getString("pwd"), res.getString("first_name"), res.getString("last_name"));
                user.setCity(res.getString("city"));
                user.setBirth(res.getDate("birth").toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate());
            }
            
            res.close();          
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new SQLException("An error occured while trying to retrieve personal information."); 
        }catch(NumberFormatException ne) {
            ne.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        } finally {
            if(stmt != null) {
                stmt.close();
            }
        }
        
        return user;
    }
```

**Connection**

```
public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException{
        
        if (conn == null) {
             conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
        }
        
        return conn;
    }
```

**RoutinesIdentifier**

```
public static final String GET_USER = "call wwj_db.retrieve_user(?);";
```

**RoutinesManager**

```
public static ResultSet bindParametersAndExec(CallableStatement stmt, int ... params) throws SQLException {
        for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
            stmt.setInt(i+1, params[i]);
        }
                
        return executeStmt(stmt);
    }

    public static ResultSet executeStmt(CallableStatement stmt) throws SQLException {
        if(stmt.execute()) {
            return stmt.getResultSet();
        }else {
            return null;
        }   
    }
```

**MySQL**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `retrieve_user` (in var_id int)
BEGIN
    SELECT `user`.email, `user`.pwd, `user`.first_name, `user`.last_name, `user`.city, `user`.birth
    FROM `account` join `user` on `account`.user = `user`.email
    WHERE `account`.id = var_id;
END
```

**Stack trace**

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid integer format for value 'PRIMARY'
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MysqlTextValueDecoder.getLong(MysqlTextValueDecoder.java:223)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MysqlTextValueDecoder.getInt(MysqlTextValueDecoder.java:152)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MysqlTextValueDecoder.decodeInt2(MysqlTextValueDecoder.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.result.AbstractResultsetRow.decodeAndCreateReturnValue(AbstractResultsetRow.java:153)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.result.AbstractResultsetRow.getValueFromBytes(AbstractResultsetRow.java:241)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.result.ByteArrayRow.getValue(ByteArrayRow.java:91)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getObject(ResultSetImpl.java:1296)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:797)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.CallableStatement$CallableStatementParamInfo.addParametersFromDBMD(CallableStatement.java:254)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.CallableStatement$CallableStatementParamInfo.<init>(CallableStatement.java:206)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.CallableStatement.convertGetProcedureColumnsToInternalDescriptors(CallableStatement.java:831)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.CallableStatement.determineParameterTypes(CallableStatement.java:805)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.CallableStatement.<init>(CallableStatement.java:586)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.CallableStatement.getInstance(CallableStatement.java:485)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.parseCallableStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:1516)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareCall(ConnectionImpl.java:1541)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareCall(ConnectionImpl.java:1532)
    at logic.persistence.dao.UserDAO.selectPersonalInfo(UserDAO.java:27)
    at logic.domain.User.getPersonalInfoFromDB(User.java:85)
    at logic.application.control.AccountControl.retrievePersonalInfo(AccountControl.java:72)
    at logic.bean.UserBean.getPersonalInfo(UserBean.java:103)
    at logic.presentation.control.PersonalInfoGraphic.initialize(PersonalInfoGraphic.java:78)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
    at logic.presentation.GraphicHandler.switchScreen(GraphicHandler.java:106)
    at logic.presentation.GraphicHandler.openSection(GraphicHandler.java:119)
    at logic.presentation.control.AccountGraphic.openPersonalInfo(AccountGraphic.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:410)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$4(WinApplication.java:187)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Help us help you - share the code for such a failing call

Comment: Which versions of MySQL Connector/J and MySQL server are you using? At first glance this would seem to be a bug in the driver (or possibly in the server).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I'm using version 8.0.22

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that "PRIMARY" datatype in database is not in INT format. Therefore, please use the respective data type in Java code whatever is there in database.

Comment: It is not that simple, the problem is inside MySQL Connector/J trying to read the database metadata to prepare the call.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel that was it!! Thank you so much. I changed both the server and the connector version and everything worked.